# Loop must iterate over collection: Account

Tags: apex, map, compile-error, loop

In the code below, I get compiler error on `Loop must iterate over collection: Account`

Can anyone help me about this issues.

```
 list<Account> acc =[Select Id, (Select Id, Name from ChildAccounts) from Account];
        Map<Id, Account> accMap = new Map<Id, Account>();
        for(account a: acc){
            for(account b: a.ChildAccounts){
                accMap.put(a.Id, b);
            }
        }
        
        Account acclst = accMap.get('00O28000004oRjdEAE');
        
        for(Account a: acclst){
            
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is expecting a list of accounts for the below `for` loop, but it is account.

```
Account acclst = accMap.get('00O28000004oRjdEAE');
for(Account a: acclst){
        
}
```

So the map should be `Map<Id, List<Account>>`, use the below code to put the values into the map.

```
Map<Id, List<Account>> accMap = new Map<Id, List<Account>>();
for(account a: acc){
    accMap.put(a.Id, a.ChildAccounts);
}
```

Finally, the for loop will be like below.

```
for(Account a: accMap.get('00O28000004oRjdEAE')){ // never use hard coded ids
        
}
```